# Why is Spring Boot 2.5.0 JMX Beans not showing in JConsole

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, jmx, spring-jmx

Using Spring Boot `2.1.6.RELEASE` for JMX Beans are working correctly or they are shown in Jconsole but in `2.5.0` it does not. The following is my simple application using spring boot 2.5.0.

If you want to try version 2.1.6.RELEASE, just change the spring-boot-starter-parent version to 2.1.6.RELEASE and the JMX Beans will work.

pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

DemoApplication.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

import java.io.IOException;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);

        System.out.print("Press [ENTER] to quit:");
        System.in.read();
    }
}
```

JmxEndpoint.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedOperation;
import org.springframework.jmx.export.annotation.ManagedResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
@ManagedResource
public class JmxEndpoint {
    @ManagedOperation
    public void printMessage() {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting `spring.jmx.enabled=true` in `application.properties` file is the solution.
They have disabled it by default in newer versions including `2.5.0`.

Reference: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/16090